# 2015 Honda Accord Dashboard lights won't turn off after draining the battery

Tags: honda, electrical, lights, battery-drain, dashboard

I'm a fairly new driver and I have zero knowledge of cars in general, today I made the mistake of sitting in my car with the ignition on but the motor not running, thus causing the battery to die.

Now all of my dashboard lights are on and won't go off, even after someone helped me jump my car to get it running.

Is there a reason that the dashboard lights won't go off?

Do I need to go get the car serviced? Or will they go off by themselves eventually?